How to implement loop playback using IMFSequenceSource as a playlist in a video player written with Media Foundation?
I called function SkipTo(0) after I received MESessionEnded media session event,the function Invoke outputed the following events in sequence: MESessionCapabilitiesChanged,MESessionStarted,MEEndOfPresentationSegment,MESessionTopologySet and MESessionTopologyStatus media session events.
BUT the Window didn't display video .
Why ?How to implement loop playback?
PLEASE tell me!!!
HRESULT CPlaylist::SkipTo(DWORD index)
{
    if (index >= segmentCount)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    MFSequencerElementId ID = segments[index].SegmentID;

    PROPVARIANT var;

    String debugStr(">>>>Segment ID is:"+IntToStr((int)ID) );
    OutputDebugString(debugStr.w_str());
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSequencerSegmentOffset(ID, 0, &var);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = mediaSession->Start(&MF_TIME_FORMAT_SEGMENT_OFFSET, &var);
        PropVariantClear(&var);
    }
    return hr;
}

I expected that the vide display the window like first play.

I solved this problem myself：
HRESULT hr = m_pSequencerSource->AppendTopology(
pTopology,
0,//SequencerTopologyFlags_Last,
&SegmentId

);
Do not pass the parameter "SequencerTopologyFlags_Last", the SkipTo function will work well
